# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.data().newUser') when navigating to Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, async-await

I use `componentDidMount` to start `fetchNewUser` when I navigate to the screen, it is supposed to recognize a new user and update it if it true, the problem is that when I navigate in the screen for the first time it returns `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.data().newUser')`, but if I refresh the screen it works.

```
  fetchNewUser = async () => {
        const fetchInformation = doc(db, 'path')
        await getDoc(fetchInformation)
        .then( async (snapshot) => {
          const newUser = await snapshot.data().newUser
          const address = await snapshot.data().mainAddress
          console.log(newUser)
          if (newUser == true || newUser == undefined) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AddressSearch')
            updateDoc(fetchInformation, {
                newUser: false
              })
          } else {
            this.setState({address: address})
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to acces newUser on the promise, what you should do instead is `const newUser = (await snapshot.data()).newUser`

Comment: now I receive the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context2.sent.newUser')`

Comment: on what browser are you testing?

Comment: I'm testing on an iPhone simulator